# Breaking swift program into multiple files

Tags: ios, swift, file, class

Surprisingly, I'm having trouble searching for this. How do I place assisting classes in separate files in Swift?
If I want to store an addition function in a separate math class in the same file, I can call math.add(), but if I want to store the class and function it in a math.swift file and reference it from the main file, what would I use?

Comment: I found a post that mentions using handlers, but it is not clear on their exact use, how they are used, or if other methods are available.

Comment: add an example of your math functions and the context you'd like to use them in.

Comment: Are you asking how to create files and new classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply looking to make a new file with your class and call it from main (or viewDidLoad). You can do the following.

- Just make a new file by right clicking on your desired folder and choosing new file.
- Choose a simple Swift file and name it Math.swift and create.
- Copy your math class into the file, it'll wind up looking something like this.

**Math.swift**

```
import UIKit

class Math {

    func add(param:Int, param: Int) {
        //... your implementation
    }
}
```

Then in main (or viewDidLoad) create an instance of your math class:

```
var myMathClass = Math()
```

then call your function:

```
myMathClass.add(5, 5) // you've called your function
```

There are quite a few different options. If you share some code and clarify your question I can help you better.

Comment: how create main class ? or how create the viewDidLoad

Comment: @x-rw are you trying to make a class with the ViewDidLoad override?